# play a tick sound when one second completes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am creating an application,in my app i am changing images for countdown. I want to play a Tick sound when one second completes(i mean when image changes).I have a 25 second long sound with repeated tick sound and within time interval of 1 second.

I am new to use sound. can anybody provides me step by step solution for adding sound ?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Metronome example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Metronome/Introduction/Intro.html) from the Apple site. It makes a ticking sound every second, every half of a second or every quarter of a second, etc.

Comment: Link is no longer available! :/

Answer (score 0):

Download the sample code for the [Pragmatic Programmer's iPhone SDK Development book](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) and look for the project labelled "SystemSoundsDemo" (in the MediaPlayback folder). It shows you how to play short sounds in response to events.

If you want more detail, I highly recommend buying the book.